# Восстановление базы данных из из файла в формате .dump

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть дам базы данных postgres в формате `.dump` Изначально файл лежит в файле архива `mydb.dump.gz` после распаковки `mydb.dump`
Как сделать восстановления с такого формата? В PgAdmin такой формат даже выбрать нельзя...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего сначала узнать как этот дамп получали. Имя у файла может быть произвольным.

---

С достаточной долей вероятности можно попробовать угадать, что у вас файл в формате `custom` характерном для `pg_dump` с опцией `-Fc`. Такой дамп восстанавливается с помощью утилиты `pg_restore`

```
pg_restore -d пустая_БД путь_к_файлу
```